# Position SVG at bottom of any screen

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to position a SVG at bottom in any screen, but I can't do it in screens without scrollbar.
I tried some changes but nothing seems work.

Here is CSS what I use:

```
    .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1652813835 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1652813835 svg {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: calc(128% + 1.3px);
            height: 600px;
        }
    
        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1652813835 .shape-fill {
            fill: var(--svg-color);
        }
```

And there is my Html:

```
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1652813835">
            <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I don't have scroll this is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kafst.png

When I have scroll the SVG fits at the bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GFDP.png

I look with element inspector and that white space is not found inside my html document.

Any sugestions please? Thanks for ur time.

**EDIT:**

This whats happens when delete the position relative in that div:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRjMt.png

**EDIT 2:**
Added JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bue4m39t/1/

Comment: You might want to research 'sticky footer' techniques

Comment: `fixed` instead of `absolute` : https://jsfiddle.net/4uw1c09k/

Answer (score 1):

to move an element out of flow and position it depending of the viewport use:  `position: fixed;`

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
```

Comment: This is what you want.

Comment: that doesn't work too, the problem is in windows with scrollbar.. I added jsfiddle so they can see it better

Comment: you never used `position: fixed` on the svg but `position: relative`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
html, body {height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: or `min-height`, even better